In app Purchase saving/sending transaction only for one user
I'm new to in app purchase integration, It's myfirst time but I'm getting the issue.
Each time i make a transaction from any device with any logged in account, it automatically saves it for the first account logged in (userid 6718d1d4c4d8cc8ae50de132) every time, how come?
I've switched account, logged out and logged another account in on my app to get a different userid, when i tried the purchase, same issue, it only gets saved for the first userid. I tried different devices too maybe it was cached, same thing.
Pls assist, I'm using the apple store notification server and i got the details below which i decode
transactiondata:  {
notificationType: 'EXPIRED',
subtype: 'VOLUNTARY',
notificationUUID: '33993256-fb6b-44c2-a6a1-e183e6936711',
data: {
  appAppleId: 6737527243,
  bundleId: '-X4JU4ZNDG.com.example.podcella',
  bundleVersion: '5',
  environment: 'Sandbox',
  signedTransactionInfo: 'eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsIng1YyI6WyJNSUlFTURDQ0E3YWd....',
  signedRenewalInfo: 'eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsIng1YyI6WyJNSUlFTURDQ0E3YWdBd0lCQWdJ...',
  status: 2
},
version: '2.0',
signedDate: 1730559317958
}
transactiondata2:  {
transactionId: '2000000762928300',
originalTransactionId: '2000000759306490',
webOrderLineItemId: '2000000079532551',
bundleId: '-X4JU4ZNDG.com.example.podcella',
productId: 'com.podcella.monthlysubscription',
subscriptionGroupIdentifier: '21571853',
purchaseDate: 1730558583000,
originalPurchaseDate: 1730257647000,
expiresDate: 1730558883000,
quantity: 1,
type: 'Auto-Renewable Subscription',
inAppOwnershipType: 'PURCHASED',
signedDate: 1730559317937,
environment: 'Sandbox',
transactionReason: 'RENEWAL',
storefront: 'NGA',
storefrontId: '143561',
price: 1900000,
currency: 'NGN'
}

below is my endpoint code
// Shared secret and Google API variables as defined in your code
const APPLE_SHARED_SECRET = process.env.APPLE_SHARED_SECRET;
const GOOGLE_PACKAGE_NAME = 'com.example.podcella';
const GOOGLE_PRODUCT_ID_WEEKLY = 'com.podcella.weeklysubscription';
const GOOGLE_PRODUCT_ID_MONTHLY = 'com.podcella.monthlysubscription';
const GOOGLE_PRODUCT_ID_YEARLY = 'com.podcella.yearlysubscription';
// const GOOGLE_API_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'your_google_api_access_token';

// Update Subscription After Purchase
const updateSubscriptionAfterPurchase = async (req, res) => {
    const { signedPayload, purchaseToken } = req.body;
    // console.log('Received notification:', req.body);

    try {
        let paymentPlan, amount, planExpiryDate, transactionData, transactionData2;

        if (signedPayload) {
            const decodedPayload = jwt.decode(signedPayload, { complete: true });
            transactionData = decodedPayload?.payload;
            console.log('transactiondata: ', transactionData);
            //second decoding
            const decodedPayload2 = jwt.decode(transactionData.data.signedTransactionInfo, { complete: true });
            transactionData2 = decodedPayload2?.payload;
            console.log('transactiondata2: ', transactionData2);


            if (!transactionData2) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Apple signedPayload decoding failed' });
            }

            paymentPlan = mapApplePlan(transactionData2);
            // amount = getAppleAmount(transactionData2);
            if (transactionData2.currency === 'NGN') {
                amount = transactionData2.price / 1000;

            } else {
                amount = transactionData2.price;

            }
            planExpiryDate = new Date(parseInt(transactionData2.expiresDate));
            // console.log(paymentPlan);
            // console.log(amount);
            // console.log(planExpiryDate);

        } else if (purchaseToken) {
            const googleResponse = await verifyGooglePurchase(purchaseToken);
            if (!googleResponse || !googleResponse.data) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Google transaction verification failed' });
            }

            const subscriptionData = googleResponse.data;
            paymentPlan = mapGooglePlan(subscriptionData);
            amount = getGoogleAmount(subscriptionData);
            planExpiryDate = new Date(parseInt(subscriptionData.expiryTimeMillis));
            transactionData = subscriptionData; // Using for uniform structure
        }

        if (!paymentPlan || !amount) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid payment plan or amount' });
        }

        const user = await User.findOne({
            $or: [
                { 'subscription.appleTransactionId': transactionData2?.originalTransactionId },
                { 'subscription.googlePurchaseToken': purchaseToken }
            ]
        });
        console.log(user?.id);
        console.log("User updated successfully");


        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
        }

        user.subscription = {
            paymentPlan,
            planExpiryDate,
            isPremiumUser: planExpiryDate > new Date(),  // Check if expired
            type: planExpiryDate > new Date() ? 'active' : 'inactive',
            appleTransactionId: transactionData?.original_transaction_id || null,
            googlePurchaseToken: purchaseToken || null,
        };
        await user.save();

        const transaction = await Transaction.create({
            userId: user._id,
            paymentPlan,
            amount,
            status: 'completed'
        });

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Subscription updated successfully!',
            transaction,
        });
        console.log("Transaction updated successfully");

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating subscription:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating subscription', error: error.message });
    }
};


// Apple Plan Mapping Function
function mapApplePlan(transactionData2) {
    const productId = transactionData2.productId;
    switch (productId) {
        case 'com.podcella.weeklysubscription':
            return 'weekly';
        case 'com.podcella.monthlysubscription':
            return 'monthly';
        case 'com.podcella.yearlysubscription':
            return 'yearly';
        default:
            return 'inactive';
    }
}


// Google verification function remains the same
async function verifyGooglePurchase(purchaseToken) {
    const url = `https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/${GOOGLE_PACKAGE_NAME}/purchases/subscriptions/${GOOGLE_PRODUCT_ID}/tokens/${purchaseToken}`;
    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${GOOGLE_API_ACCESS_TOKEN}` };

    return await axios.get(url, { headers });
}

I want transaction to update for the user that made that transaction, at the moment, only this userid is gotten 6718d1d4c4d8cc8ae50de132. despite testing the in app purchase with another device and account different account.
every time, it's alway this 6718d1d4c4d8cc8ae50de132
